# How can I use Lucene to search for documents that do not contain a term?

Tags: java, lucene

I am aware that the [Lucene documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/queryparsersyntax.html) says

> Note: The NOT operator cannot be used with just one term. For example,
>   the following search will return no results:
>
> NOT "jakarta apache"

However, I would like to be able to form a query that returns all documents NOT containing a term. I have looked into stringing together a [MatchAllDocsQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/MatchAllDocsQuery.html) and a [TermQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TermQuery.html) into a [BooleanQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_4_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html), but I cannot seem to find the right combination.

If I index the following two documents

```
Doc0: content:The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
Doc1: (empty string)
```

The query `*:* -content:fox` returns both documents when I just want one document.

The RegexQuery `content:^((?!fox).)*$` suggested by [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-string-not-containing-a-word) returns one document but it does not seem to be working correctly because `content:^((?!foo).)*$` returns one document as well when I expect it to return two documents.

I am aware of the performance implications of what I want to do. The query will only be run on a few documents so I am not too worried about performance.

Is there a way to write a Lucene query to get what I want?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use match everything and exclude the term -

```
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher("path_to_index");
MatchAllDocsQuery everyDocClause = new MatchAllDocsQuery();
TermQuery termClause = new TermQuery(new Term("text", "exclude_term"));
BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
query.add(everyDocClause, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
query.add(termClause, BooleanClause.Occur.MUST_NOT);
Hits hits = searcher.search(query);
```

Else, have a dummy field which some fixed value and use query

```
+dummy_field:dummy_value -exclude_term
```

Comment: Both of your answers work for me. MatchAllDocsQuery is preferred. At first I implemented MatchAllDocsQuery and it did not work so I asked this Question. When I got the dummy field working, I switched back to MatchAllDocsQuery for a sanity check and it worked. I am not sure why it did not work for me before. I must have gotten one of the steps wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you append an "artificial" token to each document and then search for "'added token' and not 'what you want to avoid'" ?